# putting Absent in columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have written this query to display Working time of an employee based on his `INTime` and `OutTime`, by calculating difference between it and also to calculate `OVETIME` for 2 shifts, for shift `s002` it calculates only overtime if time is above `18:00 pm` and for shift `s001` it calculates if only above `17:00`.

That's all.

Now problem is that if person doesn't come on particular day then i should put `ABSENT` in `Total WorkingTime` and `Overtime` or if His `In Time` is only mentioned then , i should put `Not Defined` in `WORKING TIME` and `OVER TIME`.

Query:

```
with times as (
SELECT    t1.EmplID
        , t3.EmplName
        , min(t1.RecTime) AS InTime
        , max(t2.RecTime) AS [TimeOut]
        , t4.ShiftId as ShiftID
        , t4.StAtdTime as ShStartTime
        , t4.EndAtdTime as ShEndTime
        , cast(min(t1.RecTime) as datetime) AS InTimeSub
        , cast(max(t2.RecTime) as datetime) AS TimeOutSub
        , t1.RecDate AS [DateVisited]
FROM  AtdRecord t1 
INNER JOIN 
      AtdRecord t2 
ON    t1.EmplID = t2.EmplID 
AND   t1.RecDate = t2.RecDate
AND   t1.RecTime < t2.RecTime
inner join 
      HrEmployee t3 
ON    t3.EmplID = t1.EmplID 
inner join AtdShiftSect t4
ON t3.ShiftId = t4.ShiftId
group by 
          t1.EmplID
        , t3.EmplName
        , t1.RecDate
        , t4.ShiftId 
        , t4.StAtdTime 
        , t4.EndAtdTime
)
SELECT 
 EmplID
,EmplName
,ShiftId As ShiftID
,InTime
,[TimeOut]
,convert(char(5),cast([TimeOutSub] - InTimeSub as time), 108) TotalWorkingTime
,[DateVisited]
,CONVERT(char(5),CASE WHEN  CAST([TimeOutSub] AS DATETIME) >= ShEndTime And ShiftID = 'S002'
     Then  LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(12), DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(ms, CAST(ShEndTime AS DATETIME),  CAST([TimeOutSub] AS DATETIME)),0), 108),5) 
     WHEN  CAST([TimeOutSub] AS DATETIME) >= ShEndTime And ShiftID = 'S001'
     Then  LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(12), DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(ms, CAST(ShEndTime AS DATETIME),  CAST([TimeOutSub] AS DATETIME)),0), 108),5) 
     ELSE '00:00' END, 108) AS OverTime
FROM times order by EmplID, ShiftID, DateVisited
```

Comment: Nothing that aims directly on your question, but maybe [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31012/query-optimization-time-intervals) gives you additional information about dealing with time-intervals, present time and absences. I've done this for a long time ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

Find Whether DateVisited NULL or NOt and Move further

```
with times as (
SELECT    t1.EmplID
        , t3.EmplName
        , min(t1.RecTime) AS InTime
        , max(t2.RecTime) AS [TimeOut]
        , t4.ShiftId as ShiftID
        , t4.StAtdTime as ShStartTime
        , t4.EndAtdTime as ShEndTime
        , cast(min(t1.RecTime) as datetime) AS InTimeSub
        , cast(max(t2.RecTime) as datetime) AS TimeOutSub
        , t1.RecDate AS [DateVisited]
FROM  AtdRecord t1 
INNER JOIN 
      AtdRecord t2 
ON    t1.EmplID = t2.EmplID 
AND   t1.RecDate = t2.RecDate
AND   t1.RecTime < t2.RecTime
inner join 
      HrEmployee t3 
ON    t3.EmplID = t1.EmplID 
inner join AtdShiftSect t4
ON t3.ShiftId = t4.ShiftId
group by 
          t1.EmplID
        , t3.EmplName
        , t1.RecDate
        , t4.ShiftId 
        , t4.StAtdTime 
        , t4.EndAtdTime
)
SELECT 
 EmplID
,EmplName
,ShiftId As ShiftID
,InTime
,[TimeOut]
,convert(char(5),cast([TimeOutSub] - InTimeSub as time), 108) TotalWorkingTime
,[DateVisited]
,CASE WHEN [InTime] IS NOT NULL AND [TimeOut] IS NOT NULL THEN
     CONVERT(char(5),CASE WHEN  CAST([TimeOutSub] AS DATETIME) >= ShEndTime And ShiftID = 'S002' Then  LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(12), DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(ms, CAST(ShEndTime AS DATETIME),CAST([TimeOutSub] AS DATETIME)),0), 108),5) 
                          WHEN  CAST([TimeOutSub] AS DATETIME) >= ShEndTime And ShiftID = 'S001' Then  LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(12), DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(ms, CAST(ShEndTime AS DATETIME),  CAST([TimeOutSub] AS DATETIME)),0), 108),5) 
      ELSE '00:00' END, 108) 
 ELSE 'ABSENT' END AS OverTime
 FROM times order by EmplID, ShiftID, DateVisited
```

Comment: Please check this answer

Comment: How would you come to know whether emplyee absent or not by this query

Comment: if no record of INtime exists for employee then absent and if Intime exists but not outtime then also absent

Comment: If Intime Not exist means then it will return null in result right?

Comment: sure, exactly or if intime exists and Out not then too

Comment: @Evilrising I have updated answer as you said. Can you check now

Comment: same problem, doesn't mention ABSENT

Comment: can you post the image